# Using DistanceMatrixService and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get the time and distance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use getlocation's position.coords.latitude/longitude as on the input for DistanceMatrixService. When I try to use these as input variable on DistanceMatrixService it brakes, doesn’t return anything. I get error saying "TypeError: element.distance is undefined"

Here is the full code.

```
function getLocation() {
        var options = null;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

function showPosition(position) {
        Currentlat = position.coords.latitude;
        Currentlon = position.coords.longitude;
        var YourLatLong = "45.4049,-122.797997";
        var DestLatLong1 = Currentlat + ',' + Currentlon;
        var DestLatLong2 = "61.221274,-149.831545";
        alert(DestLatLong1);
        GoogleMapDistance(YourLatLong,DestLatLong1);
    }

function GoogleMapDistance(YourLatLong,DestLatLong)
    {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
        origins: [YourLatLong],
        destinations: [DestLatLong],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
    }

function callback(response, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
        {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
          for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++)
          {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
              {
                  var distance = element.distance.text;
                  var duration = element.duration.text;
                  var ResultStr = distance + "&nbsp; (<i>" + duration + "</i>)";
              }
          }
        document.getElementById("Results1").innerHTML = ResultStr;
        }
    }

getLocation();
```

I have defined couple of variables just for test purpose.

```
var YourLatLong = "45.4049,-122.797997";
var DestLatLong1 = Currentlat + ',' + Currentlon;
var DestLatLong2 = "61.221274,-149.831545";
alert(DestLatLong1);
```

When I use YourLatLong/DestLatLong2 as input it works great.
I can see the the correct data in "DestLatLong1", but when I use as input it doesn’t work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it done this way, by changing the call back function.
It might help someone else.

```
function getDistance(position){
origin = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),parseFloat(position.coords.longitude));
var mylocs = [ ["12.014675", "74.760964"], ["12.019265", "78.766434"], ["15.026083", "79.758464"] ];

for (var i=0; i < mylocs.length; i++){
    destination = new google.maps.LatLng(mylocs[i][0], mylocs[i][1]);
    service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, 
        callback(i)
    );
}
}

var distance, duration;

function callback(j){
      return function(response, status) {
        if(status == "OK"){
            distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            var ResultStr = distance + "&nbsp; (<i>" + duration + "</i>)";

            document.getElementById("Results1").innerHTML = ResultStr;

        } else {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        }
      }
    }
```